# Rearrangements with alternating signs.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, absolute-convergence

This problem is present in "Supplements to the Exercises in Chapter 1-7 of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis" by Prof. George M. Bergman, which states as follows,

Show that if $(a_{n})$ is a non-absolutely convergent series, and $\alpha$ is a real number, then there exists a rearrangement $(a_{k_{n}})$ of $(a_{n})$ such that for all even $n$, $a_{k_{n}} \geq 0$, for all odd $n$, $a_{k_{n}} \leq 0$, and $\sum a_{k_{n}} = \alpha$.

This problem looks like the Riemann series theorem with constraint in the series. Can anyone give me some clues about how to construct it?

What I have got is that: first, this series must contain infinitely many positive and negative terms; second, the problem can be boiled down to this one: if the conditional series $(a_{n})$ converges to zero, find a rearrangement which also converges to zero and such that its odd terms are $\leq 0$, and its even terms are $\geq 0$. However, I stuck here for a long time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Such a rearrangement can be constructed in a stage-wise manner as we show below. Let $(b_n)$ denote the subsequence of all non-negative numbers from $(a_n)$ and let $(c_n)$ denote the subsequence of all negative numbers from $(a_n)$. As you had indicated in the question, both $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ are non-empty infinite sequences since $(a_n)$ is conditionally convergent. Let us also observe the following facts:

1. Since, $a_n$ is a conditionally convergent series, it follows that $\sum_n b_n \to \infty$ and $\sum_n c_n \to -\infty$. This is because if both of these series converge, then $a_n$ can be shown to be absolutely convergent, which is a contradiction. And if either of these series converge, then the other than can be shown to be convergent since $ \sum_n a_n$ is convergent.
2. Since $ \sum_n a_n$ converges, it follows that $a_n \to 0$ and hence $b_n \to 0$ and $c_n \to 0$.

Now, we construct the required rearrangement in a stage-wise manner by inspecting the sequences $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$. Intuitively we do the following. We inspect the sum of the finite sequence constructed until stage $k-1$, say $s_{k-1}$ and check if $s_{k-1} \geq \alpha$ or $s_{k-1} < \alpha$. If $s_{k-1} \geq \alpha$, we pair up numbers from $(c_n)$ with an *insignificant subsequence* of $(b_n)$ and walk backwards along the number line until the sum reaches below $\alpha$. That such *insignificant subsequences* exists and that the sum shall reach below $\alpha$ is guaranteed due to the observations above. Similarly, if $s_{k-1} < \alpha$, we shall pair up up numbers from $(b_n)$ with an *insignificant subsequence* of $(c_n)$ and walk forwards along the number line until the sum reaches above $\alpha$. The concatenation of such stage-wise walks can be shown to be a rearrangement with the required properties.

Let us start with the empty sequence at stage $0$ and let us say that all elements in $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ are not chosen at the start (at each stage we shall only have finitely many elements that are chosen in $b_n$ and $c_n$). At stage $k$, we us do the following:

Let $s_{k-1}$ be the sum of the finite sequence constructed in stage $k$ (where we assume that $s_0=0$). We have the following cases: either $s_{k-1} \geq \alpha$ or $s_{k-1} < \alpha$ . If $s_{k-1} \geq \alpha$, we do the following:

- Let $(b_{k_n})$ be any subsequence of elements in $(b_n)$ that are not chosen until stage $k-1$ such that for any $n$, $\lvert b_{k_n} \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2^{k+n}}$. This ensures that $0 \leq \sum_n b_{k_n} \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$ (since $b_n$'s are non-negative). Such a sequence exists since $b_n \to 0$.
- Let $(c_{k_n})$ be the sequence of all elements in $(c_n)$ that are not chosen until stage $k-1$.
- Consider the alternating sequence $c_{k_1},b_{k_1},c_{k_2},b_{k_2},c_{k_3},b_{k_3},c_{k_4},b_{k_4}\dots$. Let $l$ be the smallest number such that such that $s_{k-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{l} (c_{k_i}+b_{k_i}) < \alpha$. Such an $l$ exists since  $\sum_n c_n \to -\infty$ and $\sum_n b_{k_n} \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$.
- Let us append the sequence $c_{k_1},b_{k_1},c_{k_2},b_{k_2},c_{k_3},b_{k_3} \dots c_{k_{l}},b_{k_{l}}$ to the finite sequence we constructed until stage $k-1$ and mark these numbers as chosen in $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$.

If $s_{k-1} < \alpha$, we perform similar steps by exchanging the roles of $b$ and $c$ and ensure that the finite sequence constructed until stage $k$ has the desirable alternating negative-positive property and $s_k \geq \alpha$.

It is not hard to see that the sequence $(a_{k_n})$ constructed in this manner has the required properties. The sequence we construct is a rearrangement of $(a_n)$ since each number in $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ is eventually chosen at some stage and is never chosen thereafter. The alternating negative-positive property is ensured by the construction of the sequence. We have $\sum_n a_{k_n} =\alpha$ since the sums $s_k$ at the end of stage $k$ shall not away from $\alpha$ by more than $c_{k_{l}}+\sum_n b_{k_n}$ (or $b_{k_{l}}+\sum_n c_{k_n} $) which goes to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. This is because $b_n \to 0$, $c_n \to 0$ and we have also ensured that $\sum_n b_{k_n} \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$ (or $\sum_n c_{k_n} \geq -\frac{1}{2^k}$) at the end of stage $k$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I cannot see such construction is a rearrangement. Based on my understanding of your first to third bullet, the construction is a rearrangement of a subsequence of the original one, since from your first bullet, you require the condition of sum in $(b_{k_{n}})$. Hope I think wrong

Comment: It is true that $(b_{k_n})$ is a subsequence of $(b_n)$. But, those $b_{k_n}$'s that are not used in stage $k$ (i.e, the ones we append to the sequence constructed in the last stage), shall remain as not chosen in $(b_n)$. Since, at every stage $k$ where we handle $s_{k-1}<\alpha$, we will definitely chose the next element(s) from $(b_n)$ that is not chosen until stage $k-1$, it is guaranteed that every $b_n$ will be chosen in some future stage.

Comment: The condition in your first bullet $|b_{k_{n}}|< \frac{1}{2^{k+n}}$ seems too strong, if it is satisfied, you have to leave out lots of $b_{n}$'s.

Comment: Such a subsequence definitely exists because $b_n \to 0$, so there is no concern whether it can be satisfied or not.  You may be concerned that some $b_n$ for some small $n$ shall never be chosen by the above construction. But notice that in the next stage, the analogue of the second bullet shall be "Let $b_{{k+1}_n}$ be the sequence of all elements in $(b_n)$ that are not chosen until stage $k$". Hence, even these *initial* left out $b_n$'s are guaranteed to be chosen by the construction (in stage $k+1$ or later). Hence, the construction do not *forget* about the numbers that are not chosen.

Comment: Here $|b_{k_{n}}| < \frac{1}{2^{n+k}}$ converges geometrically, you can not generally let a sequence $(d_{n})$ converge geometrically even if $\lim d_{n} =0$, but one can pick a subsequence of $(d_{n})$ satisfying such condition. From this point of view, I cannot be persuaded that your construction does not leave out any terms.

Comment: $(b_{n_k})$ is indeed only a subsequence of $(b_n)$ and I did not claim that it is the entire sequence. And you are right that some initial $b_n$'s may not be chosen in stage $k$. But, what I claim is that the $b_n$'s that are not chosen in stage $k$ are guaranteed to be chosen later due to the following reason: In the stages where we handle $s_{k-1}<\alpha$, the construction is guaranteed to select the *very first* $b_n$ that is not chosen until stage $k$.

Comment: Let me once again try to explain why the *very first* $b_n$ (i.e, with $n$ being the smallest such number) that is not chosen until stage $k$ will be chosen in stage $k+1$. This is because, the analogue of the step in the second bullet shall be "Let $b_{k+1_{n}}$ be the sequence of all elements in $b_n$ that are not chosen until stage $k$". Notice that while the step in the first bullet selects only a subsequence, the step in second bullet selects the *entire* sequence from the start of the not chosen elements in $b_n$. Hence, the *very first* unchosen $b_n$ will be selected in stage $k+1$.

Comment: And hence, there shall never be any $(b_n)$ (or $(c_n)$) that never gets chosen since once they become the *very first* unchosen $b_n$ (or $c_n$), they are guaranteed to be chosen in the next stage where we take a forward walk (or backward walk in case of $c_n$) due to the reason in my last comment.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation, but I still need some time to think over it

Comment: You are welcome! Let me just indicate that the step that guarantees that every number shall be chosen is the one in the second bullet. In odd stages it shall look like the one in my answer. In even stages it shall look like "Let $b_{k+1_{n}}$ be the sequence of all elements in $b_n$ that are not chosen until stage $k$". And these ensure that the *very first* unchosen $c_n$ or $b_n$ will be chosen in that stage. And hence nothing is left out in the end.

Comment: The arguments works as is, but let me suggest a few changes that might make it clearer that no points are skipped. Both $\sum_n b_n$ and $\sum_n c_n$ are absolutely convergent (they are single-signed), so no rearrangment will change their sums. So put them in decreasing order of magnitude. When building the rearrangment of $(a_n)$, and the current sum is $< \alpha$, take the first remaining element of $b_n$, followed by the first remaining element of $c_n$ which is $\le \frac 12$ the preceding $b_n$ element. Similarly for when the sum $\ge \alpha$. (Continued)

Comment: When the sum is $<\alpha$, the first remaining element of $b_n$ is used. When the sum is $\ge \alpha$, the first remaining element of $c_n$ is used. Since both conditions must occur infinitely many times, neither sequence can have an unused element.