# Restricted rearrangement of every conditional convergent real series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_{n}$ is a conditionally convergent series in real field, is there a rearrangement $\sigma(n)$ such that $\sum a_{\sigma_{n}}$ is a convergent alternating series?

This problem is somehow related to my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4243653/rearrangements-with-alternating-signs). I appreciate any suggestion, thanks in advance

Comment: Please make the body of your MSE posts self-contained. Do not reply on the title for important information.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: By non-absolutely convergent, do you mean conditionally convergent? If not, then take $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Jose27 yes, it is conditional convergent, and there exists a theorem saying that conditional convergence is equivalent to absolute convergence in the real or complex field

Comment: Where did you get the idea there is such a theorem?? It is easily disproven: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n = \ln 2$$ but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n$$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

For real numbers, if $\sum_n a_n$ is conditionally convergent, and $(P_n)$ and $(N_n)$ consist of the positive and negative elements of $(a_n)$ respectively (you can include any $0$ elements in either sequence), then it is necessary that
$$\sum_n P_n = +\infty\\\sum_n N_n = -\infty$$

Because each series consists of elements of only one sign, the sequences of partial sums are monotone, and thus can only converge or diverge to $+\infty / -\infty$ (they cannot oscillate endlessly). But if both converged, then
$\sum_n |a_n| = \sum_n P_n - \sum_n N_n$ would also converge. And if only one of them converged, then $\sum_n a_n = \sum_n P_n + \sum_n N_n$ would also diverge. (There are certain details that must be demonstrated to justify both of those claims, but they are not hard to do in these cases.) So the only way to have conditional convergence ($\sum_n a_n$ converges while $\sum_n |a_n|$ does not) is for the positive and negative summations to both diverge.

Note also that because $\sum_n a_n$ converges, $\lim_n a_n = 0$. And therefore $\lim_n P_n = \lim_n N_n = 0$, since they are subsequences of $(a_n)$.

Now suppose you want a rearrangement of $\sum_n a_n$ that converges to some $r \in \Bbb R$. Start with a sum of $0$. If the current sum is $\le r$, take an element from the front of $P_n$ to add to your new arrangement. If the current sum is $> r$, take an element from the front of $N_n$ to add to your new arrangement.

Because $\sum_n P_n = +\infty$, no matter the current sum, you will eventually rise above it, and because $\sum_n N_n = -\infty$, no matter the current sum, you will eventually fall below it. This cycle repeats indefinitely. But also note that for all $m, |r-\sum_k^m a_{\sigma(k)}|$ must be $\le$ either the last $P_n$ element added to it, or the absolute value of the last $|N_n|$ element added to it. As these two sequences converge to $0$, so must $|r-\sum_k^m a_{\sigma(k)}|$.

A variant of this argument can be used to have the rearrangement take on any countable collection of limit points in $\Bbb R \cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$ you choose.

For complex series, consider their real and imaginary parts.

Comment: I guess I should have checked the other thread before posting. I'm mostly repeating what Subin Pulari explained there. (Since you hadn't mentioned it here, my description does not meet the requirement that the new arrangement alternate in sign. Unless you meant "alternating" where you said "alternative"?) Still, I'll leave this posted in case the different description of the same process is helpful.

Comment: Your answer actually is the proof of the Riemann series theorem, but please note that my question asks for additional structure of the rearrangement, that is, the rearrangement should be an alternative series.

Comment: "Alternative" Is NOT the same thing as "alternating". I already pointed out in my comment that I did not meet that requirement because you had not given it here (please do not blame other people for not understanding your typos). I only became aware of that requirement when I checked the other post. Also "not absolutely convergent" does not mean the same thing as "conditionally convergent". There are other ways a series can fail to be absolutely convergent, as Jose27's example illustrates. That series is neither absolutely nor conditionally convergent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I re-edited my post.

Comment: Okay, but now it is not "somehow related" to your other post, but practically identical, the *only* difference being that here you are not requiring the series to start off with a positive entry. Subin Pulari's post there is correct.